# How to invoke an AWS Lambda function synchronously?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Does anyone know the current and correct way to invoke Amazon AWS Lambda functions as synchronously in c#?

I want just to invoke lambda function and not to wait to complete lambda function execution.

Comment: `I want just to invoke lambda function and not to wait to complete lambda function execution.` So you mean asynchronously?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Lambda/TLambdaInvocationType.html You can set the invocation type when invoking lambda, you want event which will merely kick off the lambda.

Comment: I am assuming you mean asynchronously based on your question, however synchronously or asynchronously InvocationType arg is how you control that. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html#options explains it in a bit more detail in the context of aws cli.

Comment: I have added invocation type to event. But it is not invoking lambda function

Comment: And when you say event do you mean the InvokeRequest?